# running lasso and ridge regression on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regression, lasso-regression

I have the following code which successfully runs an OLS regression on the supplied dataset:

```
y = df['SPXR_{}D'.format(window)]
x = df[cols]
x = sm.add_constant(x)
mod = sm.OLS(y, x)
res = mod.fit()
```

How would I run lasso and ridge instead? I can't seem to find any statsmodels function or package to do this.

Updated code using sklearn:

```
y = df['SPXR_{}D'.format(window)]
x = df[cols]
x = sm.add_constant(x)
mod = linear_model.Lasso()
res = mod.fit(x, y)
print(res.coef_)
print(res.intercept_)
```

res.coef_ looks like this:

```
[ 0.  0. -0.  0. -0. -0. -0.  0.  0. -0.  0.  0.  0. -0. -0.  0. -0.]
```

Is there an issue in how I'm using the function? (perhaps I shouldn't be using statsmodels to add the alpha constants to my DF?)

Comment: consider using [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html), there are the models [`sklearn.linear_model.Ridge`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge) and [`sklearn.linear_model.Lasso`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso)

Comment: @sacul it seems to be what I'm looking for, but I don't see any option to supply my x's and y?

Comment: Take a look at the **Examples** section of the linked pages, it shows a nice little minimal example.

Comment: @sacul useful, followed it as you can see from the edit. However, either I'm not getting the results properly or the regression is not being run correctly.

Comment: Lasso has a parameter "alpha". It is a term to balance the fitting of the regression line and the number of used (i.e. non-zero) coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sacul writes, it is better to use sklearn for these things. In this case,

```
from sklearn import linear_model
rgr = linear_model.Ridge().fit(x, y)
```

Note the following:

1. The `fit_intercept=True` parameter of `Ridge` alleviates the need to manually add the constant as you did.
2. Shameless plug: I wrote [`ibex`](https://github.com/atavory/ibex), a library that aims to make `sklearn` work better with `pandas`.

Comment: IIS it that simple? Don't I need to supply some kind of value for L1 and L2 regressions?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois L1 is not part of Ridge regression. You do need to determine L2, but it has a default value. I suggest you check out [`ElasticNetCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html). Based on your comment, it might be what you're after.

Comment: It is a useful library, but it doesn't seem like it has the attributes statsmodels does. Apparently you have to run a separate function (score) with your x & y after your prior fit just to get an R^2 value for your prediction, as opposed to simply having an R^2 attribute of your fit.